# Python 3 -- [s for s in subsets(S)] and yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield, subset

This is some code that I found on the internet and it doesn't have much explanation. I am just curious to how it works. I don't fully understand the `yield` and the `[s for s in subsets(S)]` part. Any insight would be much appreciated!

```
def subsets(aList):

       if aList ==[]:   # base case
          yield []
       else:
          first = aList[0]
          rest  = aList[1:]
          for ss in subsets(rest):  # include first or don't in each
              yield ss                   # subset of rest
              yield [first]+ss

print ("\n testing subsets")
S = ['A','B','C','D','E']

ss = [s for s in subsets(S)]

print ("The subsets of",S,"are:")

print (ss)
```

Answer (score 4):

`subsets` is a generator: when you call it, you create an object that you can iterate over. Each time the iteration requests another value from it, it runs to the next `yield` statement, and produces that value. It's also recursive, so when you run it with five items, it calls itself on the last four, and so on.

So, if it's passed `['A']`, it creates a second generator which it passes an empty list `[]`. That will only yield an empty list, then finish. The main generator will receive that, yield it (`yield ss`), then `yield [first]+ss`, which will be `['A']`. Total result: `[[], ['A']]`

`[s for s in subsets(S)]` is a list comprehension. It's equivalent to:

```
ss = []
for s in subsets(S)
    ss.append(s)
```

In this case, it's kind of redundant - you could just do `list(subsets(S))` to achieve the same thing. List comprehensions are used when you want to do something to each of a collection of objects, or if you want to filter them.

Answer (score 2):

The way to understand `yield` is to imagine it's simply a return statement, with the added twist that the next time the function is called, execution continues from the yield statement.  When there are no more yields left, a `StopIteration` exception is raised.

A simpler example should clear things up:

```
>>> def foo():
...     for i in range(3):
...         yield i
... 
>>> x = foo()
>>> x
<generator object foo at 0x7f0cd5c30780>
>>> x.next()
0
>>> x.next()
1
>>> x.next()
2
>>> x.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

You can use the generator like an iterable, because `for` loops just catch and handle that `StopIteration` exception internally:

```
>>> x = foo()
>>> for i in x:
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
>>>
```

---

As for getting the subsets, there is an easier way!
Check out the recipe below:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, combinations
>>>
>>> def powerset(iterable):
...     s = list(iterable)
...     return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
>>>
>>> S = ['A','B','C']
>>> list(powerset(S))
[(),
 ('A',),
 ('B',),
 ('C',),
 ('A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('B', 'C'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C')]
```